# JavaScript text changing functionality in Html tables

Tags: javascript, html

we have an issue with using javaScript over 2 HTML pages. 
We want to change text in a table. There is a button you can press which opens a popup.

Here an example. 
If you press the "Eintragen" button it opens a popup. 
In the popup there should be a button which changes the innerHTML where the "Eintragen" button is.
So basically pressing the button in the popup should cause the "Eintragen" button to disappear and should show text instead.

Changing the text in one HTML page caused no problem. We can cause the button to disappear and showing text by pressing it. Our problem is by doing it with an extra popup where we press a button.

Here is our table and popup:
(We want to replace "Hallo" and the "Eintragen" Button through a different text with no button)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVAK8.png

And here is our code:

1. First one is the button which opens a popup (is already working)
2. Second one is the button in the popup which should trigger the JavaScript function.
3. Third one is the JavaScript code which should change the text

`<td><input id="vname" name="vname"></td>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td id="drei">Hallo<button class="button button-block"/onclick="popup(this.form)">Eintragen</button></td>`

`<button type="button" onclick="meineFunktion()">Eintragen</button>`

`function meineFunktion() {
window.close('schadensausmass.html');
document.getElementById("drei").innerHTML="test"
}`

Do you have any tips and solutions how to make this work. We are JavaScript beginners and need some help with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Don't link to images, instead put them in your question. Don't put code in an image. Post a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: >"It doesnt work" is not sufficient information to help. Please provide the minimal amount of code to reproduce the error

Comment: I couldnt embed the image. I tried it and it came this message: "You're not allowed to embed images in your posts yet, so we've included a link instead." I showed the code in an image. I wil edit it properly now.